# How do i connect to a server in windows with the smb address from mac

Tags: windows, smb

I have a server that I connect to from mac with smb://*servername*

How can I connect to this on Windows 11 without getting the IP address?

Comment: You need a DNS server for name resolution or you need to get the IP address of the Windows 11 machine.

Comment: My own IP address?

For clarification, I am using a windows machine, and want to connect to a Synology server that I can connect to from mac with smb://syn, and I do not have the IP address

Comment: You need the Synology Name and DNS Server or the IP address.   If everything is on one network, you just need the name .

Comment: well, the windows syntax is \\server\share but that does require some form of working name resolution. if the above address syntax doesn't work, then you need to consider things like WINS, mDNS, or a DNS server in order to handle name resolution.